# html/css, how to make element padding not cover over previous elements?

Tags: html, css

I have written a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pM6bh/) of the issue. I want the `span` with the padding to be pushed further down so it does not obscure the one above it. It currently appears that the layout only takes into account the content text size and ignores the padding. I would like to be able to achieve this with a generic css rule that works regardless of what padding values the overlapping span has, if that is possible.

html:

```
<span class='outer'>
    <span class='inner'>
        <span class='content'>Hello</span>
    </span>
    <span class='inner'>
        <span class='content'>
            <span id='pad-me-out'>
                World
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</span>
```

css:

```
.outer > .inner{
    clear:left;
    float:left;
}

#pad-me-out{
    background: #999;
    padding:7px 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to `#pad-me-out`

so;

```
#pad-me-out{
    background: #999;
    padding:7px 14px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Updated to `inline-block` as suggested by @tomaroo however this might not work in older browsers.**

Comment: hmmm, it works, which is great, but I thought if an element was `display:block;` it would take up the whole line i.e. 100% width, can you explain why this does not happen? or am I just plain wrong.

Comment: You can't have a block-level element inside an inline-level element, it's not proper HTML. You want to do `display: inline-block` instead. When setting up the structure of your content, you should be using block-level elements (`div`), not inline-level elements (`span`). `span`'s are best used for changing font family/weight/style, text alignment, etc.

Comment: It will display 100% width, however in your case, your wrapping elements are floated and their widths are automatic to the content, so the span is really displaying at 100% of the wrapping element.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Add the following in your css.

```
#pad-me-out{ display:inline-block; }
```

**Logic/Description:**
Span tag is an inline element & inline elements simply ignore padding hence we should define a display property which does support padding & closet to inline is inline-block.